# Dictionary Response error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdictionary

I have used this:-

```
NSString *srtUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.ptccircle.co.in/RestServiceImpl.svc/compose/0/iOS/iOS%20app/SRORTK5248/SRORTK/0/new/12-12-2016"];

NSDictionary *dicResult = [WebServiceHelper GetDataFromServer:srtUrl];
```

And I have get response :-

```
(
    {
        Status = 1;
    }
)
```

I want to check condition

```
if([[dicResult valueForKey:@"Status"]  isEqual: @"1"])
{
NSLog(@"Success");
}
else
{
NSLog(@"Unsuccess");
}
```

My issue is that, I have Unsuccess output.
Anybody can help me...

Comment: in response, check  Status is string or number? you are checking for string in above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response contains Array of Dictionary not dictionary directly, so you need to access the first object from array also your status key contains boolean value not string so check it using this way.

```
NSArray *array = [WebServiceHelper GetDataFromServer:srtUrl];
NSDictionary *dicResult = [array firstObject];
NSNumber *status = [dicResult objectForKey:@"Status"]
if ([status boolValue] == YES) {
     NSLog(@"Success");
}
else {
     NSLog(@"Unsuccess");
}
```

Comment: I Have response in NSDictionary.. 
NSDictionary *dicResult = [WebServiceHelper GetDataFromServer:srtUrl];
I can not change response in Array because i have use third party,  and get a response in dictionary format..

Comment: @HariMohan Please check your json response once because you are getting array, also try to nslog the `dicResult` and check what it is printing in console.

Comment: Actually i have used for all api
+(NSDictionary *) GetDataFromServer:(NSString *)strUrl {
    if([self hasInternetConnection])
    {
        NSString *urlString = [strUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
        NSError *err = nil;
        NSDictionary* json;

Comment: if(myData != nil) {
         json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:kNilOptions error:&err];
        }
        return json;
    }
    else
    {
        [self showAlertViewForTitle:@"Message" andMessage:@"No Internet Connection"];
        return nil;
    }
}

Comment: I have used the above code for all the api. and the json is NSDictionary. If i change into the array. then other api can not work.

Comment: @HariMohan Never add code in comment add it inside your question, you need to make another method for that return NSArray

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your result as below .
if your response Status's type is boolean .

```
if ([[dicResult objectForKey:@"Status"]boolValue]) {
     NSLog(@"Success");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `GetDataFromServer` method as below to get solution. 
In this method we will return the data which we got from server. It may be Dictionary or Array so we just return `id` object.

```
+(id)GetDataFromServer:(NSString *)strUrl
{

    NSString *urlString = [strUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
    NSError *err = nil;
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:kNilOptions error:&err];
    return json;

}
```

As we know that above method just call the url and return the response so we need to verify that what kind of object we got as response.

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.ptccircle.co.in/RestServiceImpl.svc/compose/0/iOS/iOS%20app/SRORTK5248/SRORTK/0/new/12-12-2016"];

//Calling Method
id response =[WebServiceHelper GetDataFromServer:strURL];

//checking that this is 
if (response != nil && [response isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    //Cast your response to array
    NSArray *responseArray= response;

    if (responseArray.count > 0)
    {

        if ([[[responseArray firstObject] objectForKey:@"Status"] boolValue])
        {
            NSLog(@"True");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"False");
        }
    }
}
else
{
    //check its dictionary or nil 
}
```